# No such file or directory error from os.Open

Tags: go

I am struggling to figure out an issue with os.Open. I keep getting a 'no such file or directory' error when using os.Open on a folder named templates. So I have my folder MVCApp with bin pkg src and templates in it. Then I have main in the src folder. So I have this code:

```
basePath := "templates"
templateFolder, err := os.Open(basePath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer templateFolder.Close()
```

I think it has something to do with the basePath that I am using with the open, but I cannot figure out how I need to preface "templates" in order for it to find this directory. I am sure this is an easy fix, but it has me perplexed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am 99% sure that this is a "working directory" problem. Do a quick call to list the contents of the current directory to make sure that it is in the right place.

Comment: Do you know how to make that call in Go? I am still very new to this language.

Comment: Hm, try `os.Getwd()`. It should give you the current working directory.

Comment: Okay yeah as I was afraid of I am in the directory main inside src when templates is a peer to src. So I need to back out of two folders to access templates like I want to. Not sure how to do that though...

Comment: What if you do `basePath := "../../templates"`?

Comment: Yes I found that just after I posted. Thank you for your help everything is working as intended now!!

Comment: Awesome! I posted as an answer to summarize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, it turned out that the issue was caused by the application running in an incorrect working directory.

The fix was to modify the path, as such:

```
basePath := "../../templates"
```

You can also use `os.Chdir` to change the working directory permanently (for the duration of the process), and avoid using the `../..`. More info here: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Chdir

Comment: FYI, your working directory has no relation to the application source, and is dependent on how you invoke you application. You should have a proper way to configure the template location in order to be deployed in a consistent manner.